# Create circular platform out of tiles

Tags: c++, glm

I am creating a 3d game. In this game I have a 3d model for a tile which I render in different locations using instancing.

I want to create a number of these tiles arranged so as to approximate a circle, similar to this:

[image: Image showing a tile-based approximation to a circle.]

I need to create an array of 3d vectors representing the position of the tiles in order to create this circle pattern with a given radius.

Here is the code I use to generate a square platform.

ENG_U is a constant representing a "Unit" in the game.

t is the array of positions passed to the renderer.

```
int rad = 16;

  t = new glm::vec3[(rad+rad+1)*(rad+rad+1)];
  int c = 0;
  for (int i =0;i < (rad+rad)+1;i++)
  {
    for (int j =0;j < (rad+rad)+1;j++)
    {
    t[c] = glm::vec3(i*ENG_U*1.7*2,0,j*ENG_U*1.7*2) - glm::vec3(ENG_U*1.7*2*rad,0,ENG_U*1.7*2*rad);
    c++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If your tiles are squares, they aren't going to make a circle no matter what. You'll always end up with gaps or overlaps.

Comment: But if you don't care about overlaps, polar coordinates are your friend. Use one for-loop for the radius (r), and another for the angle (theta), and place the tile at vec3(r×cos(theta)×ENG_U, 0, r×sin(theta)×ENG_U).

Comment: (Stars replaced with × symbols due to Markdown formatting rules.)

Comment: I mean making a circle in this fashion:https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-s4qeRc1nlk8/Tgq_A-viInI/AAAAAAAAAk4/Tnm4auTdweg/s1600/mineconics.png

Comment: Ahh, you should specify that in the question. It'll depend on the size of the circle more than usual.

Answer (score 1):

Same as the square except you check if the coordinate is within the circle's radius.

```
#include <vector>

int rad = 16;
float thicken = 0.5f; // between 0.0f and 1.0f
int thickened_radius2 = (int)floorf((rad + thicken) * (rad + thicken));

std::vector<glm::vec3> tiles;

tiles.reserve((rad*2+1)*(rad*2+1)); // (optional) reserve enough space for performance reason

for(int z = -rad; z <= rad; ++z){
  for(int x = -rad; x <= rad; ++x){
    if((x*x+z*z) <= thickened_radius2){ // check if tile is within circle
      tiles.push_back(glm::vec3(x, 0, z));
    }
  }
}

tiles.shrink_to_fit(); // (optional) only available in C++11 or newer
```

`tiles.data()` returns a pointer to the array `(glm::vec3 *)`

`tiles.size()` returns the length of the array `(size_t)`

If you need to copy that into a simple array:

```
#include <algorithm>


t = new glm::vec3[tiles.size()];
std::copy(tiles.begin(), tiles.end(), t);
```

But I'd just keep it in an std::vector this way you have the size() readily available. The overhead of std::vector is negligible.

`thicken` is optional but if you don't use this you'll only have 1 tile at each axis "side" of the circle. It makes a prettier circle. (Set it to 0 and see for yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm to generate the tile offsets.

```
  std::vector<glm::vec3> ps;
  int rad = 16;
  int r2 = 32;
  int c = 0;
  for (int i =0;i < (rad+rad)+1;i++)
  {
    for (int j =0;j < (rad+rad)+1;j++)
    {
      glm::vec3 p = glm::vec3(i*ENG_U*1.7*2,0,j*ENG_U*1.7*2) - glm::vec3(ENG_U*1.7*2*rad,0,ENG_U*1.7*2*rad);
      bool rm = false;
      if (length(p+glm::vec3(ENG_U*1.7,0,ENG_U*1.7)) > ENG_U*1.7*r2)
      rm = true;
      if (length(p-glm::vec3(ENG_U*1.7,0,ENG_U*1.7)) > ENG_U*1.7*r2)
      rm = true;
      if (length(p+glm::vec3(-ENG_U*1.7,0,ENG_U*1.7)) > ENG_U*1.7*r2)
      rm = true;
      if (length(p+glm::vec3(ENG_U*1.7,0,-ENG_U*1.7)) > ENG_U*1.7*r2)
      rm = true;
      if(!rm)
     ps.push_back(p);
    c++;
    }
  }
```